# Movement with Ridgidbodies ignoring gravity settings

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So im making a first person game and i've implemented this basic move script using ridgidbodies however im dealing with an issue with gravity. Regardless of the mass of the object and gravity settings in the inspector the object with this script attached to always falls at a slow pace. I know by MoveInput im constantly setting the velocity of the Y axis to 0 however if i change it to the gravity amount it pushes the object through the floor.

```
    public float MoveSpeed;
    private Rigidbody RB;

    private Vector3 MoveInput;
    private Vector3 MoveVelocity;

    private void Start()
    {
        RB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

 private void Update()
    {
        MoveInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        MoveVelocity = MoveInput * MoveSpeed;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        RB.velocity = MoveVelocity;
    }
```

Comment: Either set rigidbody's mode from Dynamic to Kinematic, or set gravity scale to 0.

Comment: Since you're using a Rigidbody you have to perform your own ground detection.  Not sure if this will help but here's a thread on it. https://forum.unity.com/threads/question-regarding-ground-detection-solved.468670/

Comment: @TomasŠvedas setting it to kinematic cancels out the gravity completely so now its no longer falling.

Comment: @jiveturkey I know itll have to do my own collision detection especially when it comes to creating a jump function. However the issue is that the object does fall but at a very very slow pace, regardless of what its mass is or what the gravity settings are. I know the issue lies with the MoveInput line in the update because of the Y velocity constantly being set to 0. I dont quite know how to work around that though.

Comment: Not sure if this helps. https://answers.unity.com/questions/599416/simulate-gravity-on-rigidbody.html

Comment: @jiveturkey That does help but i believe i just found the solution

Answer (score 0):

So keeping the same set up for the movement but changing in the fixed update from just adding velocity to instead moving the rigidbody position multiplied by the velocity

```
private void Update()
{
    MoveInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    MoveVelocity = MoveInput * MoveSpeed ;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    RB.MovePosition(RB.position + MoveVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I tested it by increasing the gravity in the inspector and it works